# Help with Event-Based Components

Tags: events, architecture, components, event-based-components

I have started to look at Event-Based Components (EBCs), a programming method currently being explored by [Ralf Wesphal](http://geekswithblogs.net/thearchitectsnapkin/Default.aspx) in Germany, in particular. This is a really interesting and promising way to architect a software solution, and gets close to the age-old idea of being able to stick software components together like Lego :)

A good starting point is the Channel 9 video [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/codefest/SACVIE-2010-Scalable-evolvable-understandable-Event-Based-Components-as-Building-Blocks-for-Software/), and there is a fair bit of discussion in German at the [Google Group on EBCs](http://groups.google.com/group/event-based-components). I am however looking for more concrete examples - while the ideas look great, I am finding it hard to translate them into real code for anything more than a trivial project.

Does anyone know of any good code examples (in C# preferably), or any more good sites where EBCs are discussed?

Comment: I'm very, very skeptical that there is anything even a little bit novel here.  It just sounds like standard "modularity" properties.  What makes you think this is something promising or new?

Comment: It's the wiring together. It seems to successfully separate all the structure into the wiring layer, which is then expressed trivially in code (and indeed is intended to be generated in the near future), and the truly small pieces of domain logic into a different sort of "piece", ie. a method in an atomic component.
The modularity is supposed to be ensured by using an essentially uniform interface for all the components, whether composite of atomic. This is an event (or delegate) as the "output" of type Action<T>, and a single method as input... though that's a bit fuzzy to me still...

Comment: Have you watched the Channel 9? It's long, but interesting.

Comment: Every time a new paradigm or technology comes about, people claim it will let you "stick software components together like legos." Functions, modules, classes, component architectures, design patterns, visual programming languages, event handlers, actors, closures, combinators, aspect oriented programming, monads, arrows, all make that claim. These techniques may be useful in their own right, but invariably, if you're not doing something trivial, or something that the components were originally designed for, you're going to need to do some real programming.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. What's potentially interesting here is the separation of wiring and "real programming". I think the Lego reference is to be taken with a sack of salt.

Comment: A truck load of salt.

Answer (score 0):

I find EBCs conceptually similar to Event Based Programming. You'll find a comprehensive treatment of the subject in [Ted Faison's Event Based Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596439), which also includes the complete source code for three types of systems of varying complexity (a file browser, a http service and a distributed workflow system) -- all written in C#.